# Are you allowed to change paddles mid game?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, racket

In table tennis, can you change paddles mid game to adjust to the opponents play style?

Answer (score 8):

No you can't change paddles mid game, according to the *[International Table Tennis Federation Handbook for 2017](https://www.ittf.com/handbook/)*:

> 3.4.2.4
>
> - A racket shall not be replaced during an individual match unless it is
>     accidentally damaged so badly that it cannot be used; if this happens the
>     damaged racket shall be replaced immediately by another which the player
>     has brought with him or her to the playing area or one which is handed to him
>     or her in the playing area.

Comment: A good first answer, backed by the quoted rule and referenced to a source. Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange.